# POST method on a PHP website using requests

Tags: python, post, web-scraping, python-requests, screen-scraping

How can I use a POST mehtod on a site like this one:

http://biblioteca.ufla.br/pergamum/mobile/consulta.php

and get the results of the next page:

http://biblioteca.ufla.br/pergamum/mobile/resultado.php

So I can format and get the data I want?

Tried to use requests but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: Can you show the code you attempted with requests?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to submit a form or something and then get the results?

You'll need to use AJAX. Here's an example of form validation with AJAX: http://www.formget.com/form-validation-using-ajax/